# C# Winforms Ultra Slow Update Of Screen Using Drawline method

Tags: c#, winforms

I've had a look around the web regarding this, but haven't found the exact answer I'm looking for or I've tried what is suggested and it doesn't work!

I'm having issues in that I have a screen which has approximately 72 Checkboxes on it in a matrix which I have connected together using lines the coordinates of which I store in a list.

To draw the lines I use the Drawline method in an override method for OnPaint to iterate through the list as follows :-

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        myPen.Width = 5;

       foreach(ConnectionLine cl in connectionLines)
       {
        g.DrawLine(myPen, cl.xStart, cl.yStart, cl.xStop, cl.yStop);
       }

        myPen.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();

    }
```

The strange thing about this is that it doesn't appear to be the lines that take the time to draw - it's now the checkboxes, if I remove the line functionality these refresh in the blink of an eye.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem could be that you are recreating the Graphics object each time the control is painted. Instead you should use the `e.Graphics` object that is provided in `PaintEventArgs`. You could also try using only one instance of Pen.

```
 private readonly Pen _myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black) {Width = 5};
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (var cl in connectionLines)
         e.Graphics.DrawLine(_myPen, cl.xStart, cl.yStart, cl.xStop, cl.yStop);
 }
```

Comment: That did the job! Thankyou - you've made my weekend alot less stressful!

Comment: Cool, no problem. Take a look at the edit I just made. You might squeeze some extra performance by reusing the Pen object as well. Don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create your own and dispose of a Graphics object. Use what is available with the event handler. ALso you should use `using` rather than calling Dispose explicitly.

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 5.0))
        {
           foreach(ConnectionLine cl in connectionLines)
                   e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, cl.xStart, cl.yStart, cl.xStop, cl.yStop);
        }
    }
```

Also, if your lines connect you should get better performance and cleaner code with Graphic's [DrawLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f956fzw1.aspx) method. You would have to change how you store your points or extract them from your conncetionLines collection before calling.

Comment: Thanks for you answer too - I will take you recommendations about having connected lines and the using part on board.